# How can I put a texture on a door created from Archipack?

Tags: texturing

I am using Archipack to generate a door. I'd like to put the door on a corridor. But I cannot put the texture on the door as I hope.

I can put a texture on one side of the door (naming as A side), however, not on the opposite side (B side). The opposite side (B side) is black. When I rotate the door 180 degree, the black side changes from A side to B side. As I mentioned I want to put the door on a corridor, however the black side is always facing the corridor. Could you help me out?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello, check the UV Editor to see if your object has been correctly unwrapped and placed on the image, if not select all and unwrap with the Smart UV Project, or mark seam and simply unwrap

Comment: Thank you for your comment! As you said, I did unwrap, plus, in the shader editor I added invert and normal map between diffuse BSDF and picture textures. Finally, I could put the texture on the both side!! Thank you for your advice